# How do I get a max number of bytes from a string?

Tags: string, .net-2.0

In .NET 2.0, I need to send some strings across the wire, but when building my packets I need to limit them to only 255 bytes.

I was going to use

```
UnicodeEncoding.GetBytes(char* chars,int charCount, byte* bytes, int byteCount)
```

MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/z2s6sc1d(v=vs.80)

but I can't compile my app with /unsafe, so this is out.

Here's the basic method I need to fill out:

```
private void GenerateSNMPObjectPacket(String value, int maxByteCount)
{
    int byteCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(value);

    if (byteCount > maxByteCount)
        byteCount = maxByteCount;

    byte[] valueBytes = new byte[byteCount];

    //somehow get UTF8 bytes into valueBytes

    //do what I do with my byte array
}
```

Comment: What should happen if more than 255 bytes are required?

Comment: @MarkByers You mean if value's more than maxByteCount of UTF8 bytes in value?  Then value gets truncated.  That's what (I believe) the unsafe method I can't use does.

Comment: The documentation doesn't specify how this is achieved. What were you hoping for? Truncation at exactly the 255th byte? Truncation at a code unit boundary? Truncation at a code point boundary?

Comment: @MarkByers I need the string truncated to give me 255 or less UTF8 bytes.  UTF8 characters are either 1 or 2 bytes, so I'm going to end up with either 254 or 255 bytes.  I'm testing the method I mentioned above, but I think that's what it does

Comment: @MarkByers apparently that method doesn't do what I thought it would, but my original request for help still remains

Comment: "UTF8 characters are either 1 or 2 bytes" - Are you sure? That's not what it says [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).